# react webpack setup - Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am currently bashing my head over this. I have a little react component I made here https://github.com/brettjthom/react-basic-table that uses webpack to bundle it. It works with the self contained example but as soon as I try to import it into another project like here https://github.com/brettjthom/react-basic-table-test, it fails with the error

```
Cannot call a class as a function
```

Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Webpack for the main component.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Options for Builds
var buildVar = process.argv.indexOf('-var') > -1;
var minify = process.argv.indexOf('-p') > -1;

// Different build types
var outputName = 'lib/react-basic-table';
outputName = outputName + (buildVar ? '-var' : '');
outputName = outputName + (minify ? '.min.js' : '.js');


var plugins = [
  new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
]
if (minify) plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()); 


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, include: /src/, loaders: ['eslint?{fix:true}']}
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel', query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        plugins: ["add-module-exports", "transform-es2015-modules-umd"]
      } }
    ]
  },

  externals: [{
    "react": {
        root: "React",
        commonjs2: "react",
        commonjs: "react",
        amd: "react"
    }
  }],

  output: {
    filename: outputName,
    libraryTarget: buildVar ? 'var' : 'umd',
    library: 'ReactBasicTable'
  },

  plugins: plugins,

  eslint: {
      failOnWarning: false,
      failOnError: true,
      configFile: './.eslintrc.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js']
  }
};
```

package.json for main component

```
{
  "name": "react-basic-table",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./lib/react-basic-table.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "classnames": "^2.1.5",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^5.8.23",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "eslint": "~2.11.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "~9.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "~0.4.0",
    "eslint-loader": "~1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "~1.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~1.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "~5.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-all": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js && node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p -d && node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -var -p -d && node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.example.js",
    "build": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js && node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -p -d && node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -var -p -d",
    "watch": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch",
    "build-example": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.example.js",
    "watch-example": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.example.js --watch",
    "lint": "eslint --fix ./src/**"
  },
  "author": "Brett Thom",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/brettjthom/react-basic-table.git"
  }
}
```

Webpack for the example

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

var config = {
    entry: './index.jsx',
    output: {filename: 'bundle.js'},
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] 
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loaders: [
                'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015',
            ]
        }]
    },
    plugins: []
}

module.exports = config;
```

package.json for example

```
{
  "name": "test-table",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "~1.13.1",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.9.0",
    "babel-core": "~6.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "~15.1.0",
    "react-basic-table": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Sure, you didn't read [ask].

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the feedback! I added the webpacks to the main post from the git repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

In https://github.com/brettjthom/react-basic-table/blob/master/package.json line 7

```
"react": "~15.1.0", // from "^0.13.3"
```

Re-build library. Then it works.

React 0.14+ have some drastic change in api.

Comment: You should be able to reference it by the name via the NPM dependency as well I believe.

Comment: However, this is helpful. To try this out I referenced the path directly to the library in node_modules. It did not work. Pulling it from node_modules to another path worked... maybe something with babel?

Comment: @BrettThom The `react-basic-table` npm package doesn't come with index.js and index.d.ts, so it cannot be auto pull by package name. You cannot reference the path insdie node_modules directly if you use webpack-dev-server as node_modules is excluded. So copying it into your own source tree is the only way for now.

Comment: Doesn't the NPM package use what is defined as main in packages.json?

Comment: @BrettThom base on npm doc, package.json main is one of the way, but most packages I worked with and created, either use index.js or a front end <package_name>.js file.

Comment: I checked the `react-basic-table` package folder, it is not even properly packaged. It come with src, example, webpack.config.* and node_modules internally, those should be excluded.

Comment: I'll try the index.js thing soon to see if it works. As far as node_modules I think that is according to default npm publish behavior. Dependencies are included. I'll make that change for the other files though. Thanks

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package
"Additionally, everything in node_modules is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don't bother adding node_modules to .npmignore."

Comment: I tried having the index.js as the entry point and it didn't matter. To me it seems like the library works  after it gets transpiled again by babel... which it doesn't do when its in node_modules.

Comment: @BrettThom The reason the example in react-basic-table works, is because index.jsx is using `import ReactBasicTable from '../lib/react-basic-table';`, not a npm package path.

Comment: Oh I know. What I mean is I made the node package use a index.js as the entry point in packages.json and it didn't change the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to import React components into a non-React application.

What I did is to have webpack bundle the React component as a library. In that case the output section of the webpack config could look like this:

```
output: {
  path: './assets/javascripts/build/',
  filename: 'MyTableComponent.js',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  library: 'MyTableComponent',
  umNamedDefine: true
}
```

The entry point for the components contains the class for the main React component, and an init() method that uses ReactDom to mount the component into a DOM node. So for example, for an imaginary Table component, the entry point for that webpack config could contain something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class MyTableComponent extends React.Component {

  render() { }

}

// Now the method that will mount this component
function init(container, props) {
  let component = (
    <EmbeddedViewer props={props} />
  )

  ReactDOM.render(component, container)
}

// Just export the init() method
export { init }
```

Finally, whenever you want to use the component, call the init method. In this example I'm using it inside a  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ base_url('assets/javascripts/build/MyTableComponent.js') }}"></script>
<script >
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready, false);

  function ready() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container')
    MyTableComponent.init(container, {})
  }
</script>
```

More info on the webpack output configuration can be found [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html).

Good luck!